# How can I get the current array index in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, syntax, foreach

How do I get the current index in a `foreach` loop?

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    // How do I get the index?
    // How do I get the first element in an associative array?
}
```

Comment: `$key` IS the current index.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In your sample code, it would just be `$key`.

If you want to know, for example, if this is the first, second, or i<sup>th</sup> iteration of the loop, this is your only option:

```
$i = -1;
foreach($arr as $val) {
  $i++;
  //$i is now the index.  if $i == 0, then this is the first element.
  ...
}
```

Of course, this doesn't mean that `$val == $arr[$i]` because the array could be an associative array.

Comment: Maybe start with `$i = 0;` and move your `$i++;`incrementor to the bottom of the loop for better readability.

Comment: @pbarney I disagree. Doing the increment at the end is a bug waiting to happen: if there is any `continue;` statement in the loop body, or anyone might reasonably add one in the future, an increment at the end doesn't work. Also, this keeps the declaration of the variable and the increment close together.

Answer (score 16):

This is the most exhaustive answer so far and gets rid of the need for a `$i` variable floating around. It is a combo of Kip and Gnarf's answers.

```
$array = array( 'cat' => 'meow', 'dog' => 'woof', 'cow' => 'moo', 'computer' => 'beep' );
foreach( array_keys( $array ) as $index=>$key ) {

    // display the current index + key + value
    echo $index . ':' . $key . $array[$key];

    // first index
    if ( $index == 0 ) {
        echo ' -- This is the first element in the associative array';
    }

    // last index
    if ( $index == count( $array ) - 1 ) {
        echo ' -- This is the last element in the associative array';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: creating a whole new array of length `count($array)` seems like a lot of overhead to avoid introducing one scalar variable

Comment: very poor naming `$index=>$key`

Answer (score 13):

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    // do stuff
}
```

**$key** is the index of each **$array** element

Comment: Not neessarily.  If your array looks like this: ` $array = array( 'cat' => 'meow', 'dog' => 'woof', 'cow' => 'moo', 'computer' => 'beep' );` the the $key of the first item would be 'cat'.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I think the index will be the key. Here are: 'cat', 'dog', ...

Comment: I don't understand why this is not the best answer on this page.

Answer (score 11):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
  if ($i === 0) {
    // first index
  }
  // current index is $i

  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The current index is the value of `$key`. And for the other question, you can also use:

```
current($arr)
```

to get the first element of any array, assuming that you aren't using the `next()`, `prev()` or other functions to change the internal pointer of the array.

Comment: +1 as an index doesn't have to be an integer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index#Computer_science

Answer (score 3):

You can get the index value with this

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val)
{
    $key = (int) $key;
    //With the variable $key you can get access to the current array index
    //You can use $val[$key] to

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$key` is the index for the current array element, and `$val` is the value of that array element.

<strike>The first element has an index of 0. Therefore, to access it, use `$arr[0]`</strike>

To get the first element of the array, use this

```
$firstFound = false;
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
    if (!$firstFound)
       $first = $val;
    else
       $firstFound = true;
    // do whatever you want here
}

// now ($first) has the value of the first element in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the first element in the [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) function as well.  Or [`array_search()`](http://php.net/array_search) the keys for the "index" of a key.  If you are inside a `foreach` loop, the simple incrementing counter (suggested by kip or cletus) is probably your most efficient method though.

```
<?php
   $array = array('test', '1', '2');
   $keys = array_keys($array);
   var_dump($keys[0]); // int(0)

   $array = array('test'=>'something', 'test2'=>'something else');
   $keys = array_keys($array);

   var_dump(array_search("test2", $keys)); // int(1)     
   var_dump(array_search("test3", $keys)); // bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

well since this is the first google hit for this problem:

```
function mb_tell(&$msg) {
    if(count($msg) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    //prev($msg);
    $kv = each($msg);
    if(!prev($msg)) {
        end($msg);

        print_r($kv);
        return ($kv[0]+1);
    }
    print_r($kv);
    return ($kv[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @fabien-snauwaert's answer but simplified if you do not need the original key

```php
$array = array( 'cat' => 'meow', 'dog' => 'woof', 'cow' => 'moo', 'computer' => 'beep' );
foreach( array_values( $array ) as $index=>$value ) {

    // display the current index +  value
    echo $index . ':' . $value;

    // first index
    if ( $index == 0 ) {
        echo ' -- This is the first element in the associative array';
    }

    // last index
    if ( $index == count( $array ) - 1 ) {
        echo ' -- This is the last element in the associative array';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```