# php - get index of item from foreach?

Tags: php, post, foreach, indexing

I need to go through `$_POST`, but I don't know which indexes are used (i want to be able to update multiple users values(inputs have user ID as name). When I go through `$_POST` with foreach I'm getting the values, but I don't know how to get `user_id(index)`

```
if(isset($_POST['credit_update'])){
foreach($_POST as $current){
}
}
```

i need to get index of `$current`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se. What you ask for is a very basic and fundamental language feature and you should have at least read all manual pages of the keywords you use in your code before asking a question, like http://php.net/foreach.

Comment: Also the first entry in the related column is: [PHP,how to get current index in a foreach loop for array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1450157/367456) - look for existing questions before posting your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all about foreach in [the manual](http://php.net/foreach). Here is the specific syntax you are looking for:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $current){
    //Do something
}
```

If you just want to update the array you can also get the element by reference in this way:

```
foreach($_POST as &$current){
    //If you update $current inside the loop
    //the element will be updated in the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $index=>$current){
      //$index now contains the index
}
```