# Get the value of indexed array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is an easy answer, almost too easy that it makes searching for it kinda of hard...

**PHP Foreach:**

```
<?php $position = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_moon_draggable_values', false);                                     
            if ($position){ 
              foreach ($position as $key => $value)
                    echo "{$key} => {$value}\n";  
            }                             
?>
```

This outputs `0 => 233px 1 => 435px` all Im trying to do is, select the index and echo it, I tried something like `echo $value[1]` hoping to echo the 435px, that didnt work, also trying with `$key`.

**Conclusion:** Trying to get a specific array index value 0,1 are the only two indexes (only two arrays)

**Solution:**

```
<?php $position = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_moon_draggable_values', false);                                     

                  $top  = $position[0];
                  $left = $position[1];  

?>  
<div style="left:<?php echo $left ?>; top: <?php echo $top?>; position: absolute;">

<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(get_post_meta ($post->ID, '_moon_sortable_content', true));?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450157/how-can-i-get-the-current-array-index-in-a-foreach-loop

Comment: Yeah, for instance:

`echo $position[$key]`

Comment: Oh wow, I should have tried that one also... is it clean and proper to `$top = $position[1]` `$left = $position[0]`?? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If your array is `$position = array('top' => '235px', 'left' => '432px');` You would call top with $position[0], and left with $position[1]

Comment: Lol yeah you're right I hurried and typed that example, but that is deemed good practice?

Comment: You can do `list($left, $top) = $position;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I'd go about doing it like this:

```
    //Define the position array:
    $position = array("left" => "235px",
                      "top"  => "432px");

    //Checking the position array:
    if(is_array($position))
        //Echo the information.
        echo "Left: " . $position["left"] . ", Top: " . $position["top"];
```

As for your question on if it's deemed good practice, I personally don't see why it wouldn't be.

And if for some reason, you don't have the luxury of defining the index itself, do the following:

```
    //Define the position array:
    $position = array("235px", "432px");

    //Checking the position array:
    if(is_array($position))
        //Echo the information.
        echo "Left: " . $position[0] . ", Top: " . $position[1];
```

Comment: Nice answer, except the array comes from information on the database, if something changes in the backend its put on the database the left & top positions constantly change, I wasnt so specific about that... I just want to make sure its the cleanest most optimal way to output it, I updated the OP with the code I am using now...

Comment: Thanks again, I am really enjoying learning about working with arrays.. they can be very easy at times and very confusing if working with a lot of data, but they are AWESOME.. PHP is fantastic...