# Getting the position (index) of an object in foreach?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a simple foreach block in my view, like below.

```
@foreach ($teams as $key => $team)
{{ str_ordinal($key + 1) }}
@endforeach
```

Right now I'm displaying the key, although it isn't exactly accurate. Here's an image:

[image]

How can I display the actual position of the current iteration? I order by my `teams` collection but I'm not sure how I get the position of the current interation in that loop?

Comment: You want to display the value of the current index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current array index in a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450157/how-can-i-get-the-current-array-index-in-a-foreach-loop)

Comment: How **should** the output look like? What do you mean by "actual position"?

Answer (score 145):

You can use `$loop->index` to get the index. [Check its docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable). For instance:

```
@foreach ($teams as  $team)
{{ $loop->index }}
@endforeach
```

Will display 0,1,2,3,4... until the last element position.

Comment: What's `$loop`? If you mean `$teams` then that wont work. If you mean Laravel's `$loop` then it throws `Undefined property: stdClass::$interation`

Comment: Loop actually starts with 0, so it displays 0,1,2,3,..

Answer (score 37):

You can apply `array_values` to your data before passing to template:

```
array_values($teams);
```

Or, according to this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable, you can use special `$loop` variable. I suppose you need `$loop->iteration` property (it starts with `1`) or `$loop->index` (starts with `0`):

```
@foreach ($teams as $key => $team)
    {{ $loop->iteration }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: That throws `Undefined property: stdClass::$interation `

Comment: `iteration`, without `N`.

Comment: `$loop->iteration` is exactly what I looked for, thank you for your elaborated answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $loop->index+1}}</td>
        <td>{{ $team->name}}</td>
        <td>{{ $team->caption}}</td>
        <td>{{ $team->address}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. You will get them in order.

```
$count = count($teams) ;
for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
    // your code here using $i as the position 
}
```

Comment: This is using a for, I'm using a foreach in blade, I don't think blade supports for.

Comment: Blade 100% supports `for` loops, just use `@for($i ...) ... @endfor` See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops for reference.

Answer (score 0):

**In Controller**

```
 foreach ($partners as $key => $partner) {
            $data['id'] = $key + 1;
 }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why do you try to modify any `id` value?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue with the combination of built in [loop](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable) variable and [php directive](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#raw-php)

```
*this is wrong* You cannot use it directly in double curly braces
     {{ $loop->index }}
```

Instead use  it like this,

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
   @php($count= $loop->index + 1)
      <tr>
           <th>{{ $count }}</th>
           <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
           <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
           <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
      </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Though $loop variable is available inside foreach, you cannot use it inside the curly braces in blade template.

Answer (score 0):

use this only it works fine {{$key+1}}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).